# Unable to get req.file when I send a POST with an excel file

Tags: java, excel, http-post, multipartform-data

My backend works when I send an excel file through Postman. The file is uploaded, so it working fine from the backend. Please view the following picture:

[image: Post of an Excel file with Postman]

However, when I am trying to do the same thing from the frontend, my req.file is undefined:

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
at C:\music_store\oms_server\routes\file.js:18:31
```

Here is the code of the frontend:

```
export async function postExcel({ commit }, formData) {

console.log("Entro a postExcel");
console.log(formData);

const option={
    method: 'POST', 
    body: formData };

    await Vue.axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/uploadExcel`, formData, {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        } })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error al crear archivo en DB: ", error.message);      
    }).finally(() => { 
        console.log("Petición de formData resuelta");
    });
```

Here is the code of the backend:

```
router.post('/uploadExcel', excelUpload.single('file'), async (req= request, res = response) => {

try {
    const name = req.file.filename;
    const fileJson= {
        "name": "NA",
        "route": '/uploads',
    }
   fileJson["name"] = name;

    const file = new File(fileJson);
    await file.save();
    res.json({
        "response": "archivo guardado"
    });  
}
catch (err) { 
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
 }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to my frontend, and it worked:

```
    <template>
  <div>
 <b-col  cols="4" class="justify-content-md-center">
     <br> 
      <b-form-file
      v-model="file1"
      :state="Boolean(file1)"
      placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
      drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
    ></b-form-file>
    
 
  </b-col>
   <b-col cols="2">
   <div id="selectedFile" class="mt-3">Selected file: {{ file1 ? file1.name+" cargado" : '' }}</div>
   <b-button variant="success" @click="handleFileUpload()">Button</b-button>
   </b-col>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file1: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("excel", ["postExcel"]),
    onSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("cargar archivo");
    },
    handleFileUpload() {
      try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      if(this.file1!=null){
        console.log(this.file1);
        formData.append('file', this.file1); 

        }else {
          alert("archivo vacio"); 
          return;
        }

      //Inspecting formData
      console.log("Inspecting formData"); 
      for (let entry of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(entry);
      }  
        this.postExcel(formData);
        var selectedFile=document.getElementById("selectedFile");
        selectedFile.style.color="green"
      
      }
      catch(err){
        selectedFile.style.color="red"
      }


    },
  },
};
</script>
```